# Nikon D600 - shot raw but ended up with 2x JPG

Tags: nikon, raw, file-format, file-transfer

I have been using a Nikon D600, and I thought I was using the raw mode (it said RAW on the screen). However after copying from the card to my computer, I have only managed to get a set of paired jpegs (one has a parenthetical number after it). The paired files have similar, but slightly different file sizes.  Does anyone know what has happened here?

I know it's the kind of thing that would be in the manual, but I no longer have access to it.

Comment: https://support.nikonusa.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/17980

Comment: Assume this is after transferring to computer.  How did you do that? Using Nikon View, or just copy/paste?  The parenthetical number is an indication of a duplicate file - my guess that's at the computer end of thing - unlikely you had duplicates on the card.  Please list software used, if any.  What do you see on the card? Do you have the Nikon raw codec installed on your computer?  Mac or Windows?

Comment: @MikeW I copy/pasted it on a windows machine. I don't have the card any more, though I have asked the person who does to have another look. If it wasn't for the numbers increasing and the files having different (but very similar) sizes I would be with you on the duplicate thing.

Answer (score 1):

As Darkcat posted in the comments the manual is available online at https://support.nikonusa.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/17980

The D600 takes 2 SD cards and can be set to put raw on one and JPEG on the other.  That sounds like what's happened here and the reason why you saw the camera set to raw but you only found JPEG files on the card.  You probably need to look for another card which will contain the raw files.

Because of the DCF (file naming) specification used by Nikon and other manufacturers the camera would not have added files with a parenthetical number.  Something else has done that like another piece of software that has been run on the card perhaps, you'll need to look in more detail at what has happened to the card after it left the camera to find out what or who did that.